# how to draw thousand of circles at once openCv faster - (Maybe use GPU)

Tags: python, opencv, parallel-processing, gpu

I need to draw thousands of dots on a given area of an image (frame of a video).

Using a loop is the easiest way to do this.

```
    while i < num:
        x = random.randint(min_x, max_x)
        y = random.randint(min_y, max_y)
        //this if is to check the the random points are within the original shape
        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour, (int(x), int(y)), False)==1:
            cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 2, color, -1)
            i = i+1;
```

this process takes a long time to complete.

how can I achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: https://opencv.org/platforms/cuda/ welcome.

Comment: enumerate all points inside the contour (you can draw the filled contour on a black image with `fillPoly`, and then retrieve all non zero pixels). Then just randomly select N points as yourcenters (and you don't need to check again if it's inside the polygon)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to speed it up using several tricks:

Try to get rid of the loop and vectorize your operations.
You can vectorize the (x, y) point generation by passing `size` to `random.randint`. If after filtering they don't amount to `num`, you can generate another set.

Instead of `pointPolygonTest`, maybe you can try `matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points` that operates on a vector of points rather than a single point.

For the circle, once you filter all your circle centers, create an all zeros image to draw your circles, then mark centers in this image (again, vectorize). If you want color circles you'll have to set the pixel value to appropriate gray level for each channel. Then dilate using a circular structuring element having the required radius. For small radii, these circles should be fine. Or, you can try Gaussian blur as well, because, if you convolve a Gaussian with an impulse, it'll give you a Gaussian, and a symmetric Gaussian will resemble a circle in the image. You can also use filter2D to do this if your circles have the same size. If the dilation result isn't good, you can create your own kernel resembling the circle you want, then convolve it with centers image.

Copy all non-zero pixels from this `circles` image to your `img` using the `circles` image as a mask.

A simple example for creating circles:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# create random centers for circles
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(256, 256))
img = np.uint8(img < 1) * 255
# use Gaussian bluer to create cricles
img1 = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 3)*20
# use morphological dilation bluer to create cricles
se = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
img2 = cv.dilate(img, se)
```

Centers:

[image: centers]

Circles using dilation:

[image: dcircles]

Circles using Gaussian blur:

[image: gcircles]

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am having trouble understand the 3rd point, what do u mean by dilate using a circular structuring element

Comment: @Eshaka After marking the centers, create a circular structuring element with the desired radius, then use `morphologyEx` and do a dilation, or just use `dilate`.

Comment: @Eshaka Added an example for creating circles, as I may not have been clear in the explanation.